# How to fetch nested data using JSON_VALUE when it contains an array of objects

Tags: sql, oracle, json-value

I have a table `MYTABLE` which has 3 columns as mentioned below.

```
|id | myclob_column | column3|
```

It has one column (`myclob_column`) which is clob data (json). Sample clob data is below.

```
{
"name" : "Rahul",
"address" : [ {"street" : "100"}, {"street" : "200"} .....]
}
```

I want to get all the rows from the table which has `street` value '200'.

Below select query is working when we are hard-coding the position (in our case [1]) :

```
select * from MYTABLE where JSON_VALUE(`myclob_column`, $.address[1].street) = '200';
```

But I can't hard-code the position of `address` as the value (200) can be in any position. So I need to have a generic query to match the `street` as 200 in any position. I tried many things but not able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `json_table` to convert the JSON data into rows and columns in a table :

```
select  t.*
from mytable t, json_table( myclob_column , '$.address[*]'
                COLUMNS (street PATH '$.street')
               )
where STREET = 200
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/INf6iGNP)

Comment: Thanks. This works. Now if I have another field "channel" (array)  apart from name & address, then how would I get the data with channel value. Say like this  {
"name" : "Rahul",
"address" : [ {"street" : "100"}, {"street" : "200"} .....],
"channel" : ["A", "B"]
}
If want to use filter with channel value "A" and street value "200", then how to write this query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this update : https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle19/ba656f0b06898e59e00a5e5e792c70fe/

Answer (score 1):

you can parse JSON value and add condition without hardcoding as below,

```
select 
  * 
from 
mytable t1, 
JSON_TABLE(t1.clob_column,'$.address[*]' 
           COLUMNS 
           (STREET varchar PATH '$.street')
) t2 
where t2.street = '200';
```

you can see the live sql [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/o4sw4vekmtl76balpfob1rnq2)

Comment: Thanks. This works. Now if I have another field "channel" (array)  apart from name & address, then how would I get the data with channel value. Say like this  {
"name" : "Rahul",
"address" : [ {"street" : "100"}, {"street" : "200"} .....],
"channel" : ["A", "B"]
}
If want to use filter with channel value "A" and street value "200", then how to write this query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `json_exists` with predicate on array elements:

```
SQL> with sample as (
  2    select 1 as id, to_clob('{
  3      "name" : "Rahul",
  4      "address" : [ {"street" : "100"}, {"street" : "200"}]
  5      }') as val from dual
  6    union all
  7    select 2 as id, to_clob('{
  8      "name" : "Rahul",
  9       "address" : [ {"street" : "100"}, {"street" : "300"}]
 10    }') as val from dual 
 11  )
 12  select
 13    sample.*
 14  from sample
 15  where json_exists(val, '$.address[*]?(@.street == "200")')

        ID VAL                                                                             
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 {                                                                               
               "name" : "Rahul",                                                           
               "address" : [ {"street" : "100"}, {"street" : "200"}
```

**UPD**: If you want to use `json_table` with `where` filter, then it would be better to use `exists` predicate or use lateral join with a subquery accessing the table not to explode the result set if there are multiple rows with required value.

Assuming this sample data (with one more `street: 200` entry):

```
create table sample as
  select 1 as id, to_clob('{
    "name" : "Rahul",
    "address" : [ {"street" : "100"}, {"street" : "200"}, {"street": "200"}]
    }') as val from dual
  union all
  select 2 as id, to_clob('{
    "name" : "Rahul",
     "address" : [ {"street" : "100"}, {"street" : "300"}]
  }') as val from dual
```

Cross join:

```
select
  sample.*
from sample,
    json_table(
      val
      , '$.address[*]'
      columns (street PATH '$.street')
    ) flt
where flt.street = '200'
```

| ID | VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { "name" : "Rahul", "address" : [ {"street" : "100"}, {"street" : "200"}, {"street": "200"}] } |
| 1 | { "name" : "Rahul", "address" : [ {"street" : "100"}, {"street" : "200"}, {"street": "200"}] } |

`exists`:

```
select
  sample.*
from sample
where exists (
    select null
    from json_table(
      val
      , '$.address[*]'
      columns (street PATH '$.street')
    )
    where street = '200'
  )
```

or `cross join lateral` with subquery:

```
select
  sample.*
from sample
  cross join lateral (
    select null
    from json_table(
      val
      , '$.address[*]'
      columns (street PATH '$.street')
    )
    where street = '200'
      and rownum = 1
  )
```

| ID | VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { "name" : "Rahul", "address" : [ {"street" : "100"}, {"street" : "200"}, {"street": "200"}] } |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0ZnY-qSE)